# Use VBA to select last value to designate total in waterfall chart in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and trying to creating an automated table that will generate a waterfall chart where the number of data points in the chart depends on the inputs.

I would like to use VBA to create a macro that would do two things:

1) Clear all previous subtotals in the waterfall chart

2) Identify the last data point and make it a subtotal on the chart.

Recording a macro, I was able to create the following code:

```
Sub LastDataPointSubtotal()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(5).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(5).IsTotal = True
End Sub
```

I believe this script is a good start, but it does not work if the last data point is in a series containing more/less than 5 data points. It also needs a way to select all the values other than the last to make sure the IsTotal = False.

Thanks

Comment: Does the maximal number of point limited? If yes, you do not need any macro and can manage by simple **in-sheet** formulae.

Comment: The table builds automatically and the number of points varies per pull. The issue I have is if the previous pull had 4 points, and I set the last value as a subtotal and the next pull has 7, the 4th point still shows as a subtotal on a data refresh and the 7th will not. If there is a workaround not requiring VBA, I would be keen to hear the details.

Comment: How comfortable are you with Excel (including sheet functions)? If _quite comfortable_, you can achieve what you need by setting a cell with a formula such that (this is just an example): _If the next input cell is empty, the current is the last and hence calculate the total_. Yes, this is too simplified, but it is not that far from what you need (if I understood your problem of course).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. While I was not able to figure out how to do this as a function, I did piece together the following script. It's not pretty, but gets the job done.

```
Sub WaterfallAdjust()
    Sheets("BIDash").Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate

Dim pt As Long
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
     For pt = 1 To .Points.Count
          ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(pt).IsTotal = False
     Next
End With
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
     For pt = .Points.Count To .Points.Count
          ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(pt).IsTotal = True
     Next
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simpler code to format the first and last points as totals.

```
Sub HighlightTotals()
  With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
    .Points(1).IsTotal = True
    .Points(.Points.Count).IsTotal = True
  End With
End Sub
```